# RDP connections failing under specific circumstances

Tags: networking, rdp, ip-fragmentation

**Problem**

RDP connections from PCs or servers in both branch sites to the RDSH server in the main site are intermittently failing with the following error:

```
A licensing error occurred while the client was attempting to connect (Licensing timed out).
Please try connecting to the remote computer again.
```

**Configuration**

The main site is using a ZyXEL ZyWALL USG 50, is assigned subnet 192.168.169.0/24 and, hosts RDSH server 192.168.169.4.

The branch site that I've been using for diagnostics is using a Cyberoam CR10iNG, is assigned subnet 192.168.170.0/24, and hosts server 192.168.170.2.

All sites are connected via site-to-site IPsec VPNs.

All UTMs' LAN and WAN interfaces' MTU values are 1500 (this is relevant later).

**Diagnostics**

I've managed to determine two patterns to this:

1. The problem only occurs when trying to connect ~2 minutes after the previous connection attempt / the problem doesn't occur when trying to connect ~1 minute after the previous connection attempt.
2. The problem only occurs after the authentication stage.

Branch site UTM inbound and outbound packet capture when the problem occurs:

```
console> tcpdump ' host 192.168.170.2 and host 192.168.169.4
tcpdump: Starting Packet Dump
15:01:53.093210 PortA, IN: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [S], seq 2596326655, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
15:01:53.093838 ipsec0, OUT: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [S], seq 2596326655, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
15:01:53.123625 ipsec0, IN: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [S.], seq 2739636351, ack 2596326656, win 8192, options [mss 1394,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
15:01:53.123914 PortA, OUT: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [S.], seq 2739636351, ack 2596326656, win 8192, options [mss 1394,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
15:01:53.124049 PortA, IN: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [.], ack 1, win 261, length 0
15:01:53.124205 ipsec0, OUT: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [.], ack 1, win 261, length 0
15:01:53.124297 PortA, IN: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 1, win 261, length 19
15:01:53.124498 ipsec0, OUT: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 1, win 261, length 19
15:01:53.161897 ipsec0, IN: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [.], ack 20, win 514, length 0
15:01:53.161911 ipsec0, IN: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [P.], ack 20, win 514, length 19
15:01:53.162228 PortA, OUT: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [.], ack 20, win 514, length 0
15:01:53.162235 PortA, OUT: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [P.], ack 20, win 514, length 19
15:01:53.365124 PortA, IN: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [.], ack 20, win 261, length 0
15:01:53.365350 ipsec0, OUT: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [.], ack 20, win 261, length 0
15:01:56.169042 ipsec0, IN: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [P.], ack 20, win 514, length 19
15:01:56.169354 PortA, OUT: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [P.], ack 20, win 514, length 19
15:01:56.169497 PortA, IN: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [.], ack 20, win 261, options [nop,nop,sack 1 {1:20}], length 0
15:01:56.169717 ipsec0, OUT: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [.], ack 20, win 261, options [nop,nop,sack 1 {1:20}], length 0
15:01:58.770755 PortA, IN: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 20, win 261, length 141
15:01:58.771026 ipsec0, OUT: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 20, win 261, length 141
15:01:58.810913 ipsec0, IN: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [P.], ack 161, win 514, length 1209
15:01:58.811110 PortA, OUT: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [P.], ack 161, win 514, length 1209
15:01:58.838206 PortA, IN: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 1229, win 256, length 134
15:01:58.838396 ipsec0, OUT: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 1229, win 256, length 134
15:01:58.870753 ipsec0, IN: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [P.], ack 295, win 513, length 59
15:01:58.870943 PortA, OUT: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [P.], ack 295, win 513, length 59
15:01:58.871956 PortA, IN: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 1288, win 256, length 197
15:01:58.872149 ipsec0, OUT: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 1288, win 256, length 197
15:01:58.901929 ipsec0, IN: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [P.], ack 492, win 512, length 1237
15:01:58.901944 PortA, OUT: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [P.], ack 492, win 512, length 1237
15:01:58.905117 PortA, IN: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [.], ack 2525, win 261, length 1394
15:01:58.905130 ipsec0, OUT: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [.], ack 2525, win 261, length 1394
15:01:58.905271 PortA, IN: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 2525, win 261, length 339
15:01:58.905286 ipsec0, OUT: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 2525, win 261, length 339
15:01:58.935194 ipsec0, IN: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [.], ack 2225, win 506, length 0
15:01:58.935208 PortA, OUT: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [.], ack 2225, win 506, length 0
15:01:58.935211 ipsec0, IN: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [.], ack 2225, win 512, length 0
15:01:58.935225 PortA, OUT: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [.], ack 2225, win 512, length 0
15:01:58.935663 ipsec0, IN: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [P.], ack 2225, win 512, length 261
15:01:58.935675 PortA, OUT: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [P.], ack 2225, win 512, length 261
15:01:58.936427 PortA, IN: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 2786, win 260, length 437
15:01:58.936441 ipsec0, OUT: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 2786, win 260, length 437
15:01:58.965251 ipsec0, IN: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [P.], ack 2662, win 510, length 373
15:01:58.965265 PortA, OUT: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [P.], ack 2662, win 510, length 373
15:01:58.966104 PortA, IN: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3159, win 258, length 197
15:01:58.966117 ipsec0, OUT: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3159, win 258, length 197
15:01:58.966183 PortA, IN: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3159, win 258, length 469
15:01:58.966198 ipsec0, OUT: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3159, win 258, length 469
15:01:59.009189 ipsec0, IN: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [.], ack 3328, win 507, length 0
15:01:59.009203 PortA, OUT: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [.], ack 3328, win 507, length 0
15:01:59.009206 ipsec0, IN: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [.], ack 3328, win 514, length 0
15:01:59.009219 PortA, OUT: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [.], ack 3328, win 514, length 0
15:01:59.009403 ipsec0, IN: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [P.], ack 3328, win 514, length 149
15:01:59.009415 PortA, OUT: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [P.], ack 3328, win 514, length 149
15:01:59.009822 PortA, IN: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3308, win 258, length 53
15:01:59.009840 ipsec0, OUT: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3308, win 258, length 53
15:01:59.009889 PortA, IN: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3308, win 258, length 37
15:01:59.009900 ipsec0, OUT: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3308, win 258, length 37
15:01:59.038280 ipsec0, IN: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [.], ack 3418, win 514, length 0
15:01:59.038294 PortA, OUT: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [.], ack 3418, win 514, length 0
15:01:59.038521 ipsec0, IN: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [P.], ack 3418, win 514, length 37
15:01:59.038535 PortA, OUT: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [P.], ack 3418, win 514, length 37
15:01:59.038936 PortA, IN: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3345, win 258, length 53
15:01:59.038949 ipsec0, OUT: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3345, win 258, length 53
15:01:59.074195 ipsec0, IN: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [P.], ack 3471, win 514, length 53
15:01:59.074209 PortA, OUT: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [P.], ack 3471, win 514, length 53
15:01:59.074601 PortA, IN: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3398, win 257, length 53
15:01:59.074614 ipsec0, OUT: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3398, win 257, length 53
15:01:59.101963 ipsec0, IN: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [P.], ack 3524, win 514, length 53
15:01:59.101976 PortA, OUT: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [P.], ack 3524, win 514, length 53
15:01:59.102388 PortA, IN: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3451, win 257, length 53
15:01:59.102402 ipsec0, OUT: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3451, win 257, length 53
15:01:59.131316 ipsec0, IN: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [P.], ack 3577, win 513, length 53
15:01:59.131330 PortA, OUT: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [P.], ack 3577, win 513, length 53
15:01:59.131741 PortA, IN: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3504, win 257, length 53
15:01:59.131755 ipsec0, OUT: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3504, win 257, length 53
15:01:59.163405 ipsec0, IN: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [P.], ack 3630, win 513, length 53
15:01:59.163418 PortA, OUT: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [P.], ack 3630, win 513, length 53
15:01:59.163838 PortA, IN: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3557, win 257, length 53
15:01:59.163851 ipsec0, OUT: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3557, win 257, length 53
15:01:59.190262 ipsec0, IN: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [P.], ack 3683, win 513, length 53
15:01:59.190275 PortA, OUT: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [P.], ack 3683, win 513, length 53
15:01:59.190680 PortA, IN: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3610, win 257, length 53
15:01:59.190694 ipsec0, OUT: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3610, win 257, length 53
15:01:59.217563 ipsec0, IN: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [P.], ack 3736, win 513, length 53
15:01:59.217577 PortA, OUT: IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: Flags [P.], ack 3736, win 513, length 53
15:01:59.302857 PortA, IN: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3663, win 256, length 437
15:01:59.302869 ipsec0, OUT: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3663, win 256, length 437
15:01:59.589676 PortA, IN: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3663, win 256, length 437
15:01:59.589689 ipsec0, OUT: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3663, win 256, length 437
15:02:00.198617 PortA, IN: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3663, win 256, length 437
15:02:00.198631 ipsec0, OUT: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3663, win 256, length 437
15:02:01.399393 PortA, IN: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3663, win 256, length 437
15:02:01.399409 ipsec0, OUT: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3663, win 256, length 437
15:02:02.600639 PortA, IN: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3663, win 256, length 437
15:02:02.600653 ipsec0, OUT: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3663, win 256, length 437
15:02:03.802102 PortA, IN: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3663, win 256, length 437
15:02:03.802115 ipsec0, OUT: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3663, win 256, length 437
15:02:06.204902 PortA, IN: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3663, win 256, length 437
15:02:06.204918 ipsec0, OUT: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3663, win 256, length 437
15:02:11.009880 PortA, IN: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3663, win 256, length 437
15:02:11.009895 ipsec0, OUT: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [P.], ack 3663, win 256, length 437
15:02:20.619699 PortA, IN: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [R.], seq 4173, ack 3663, win 0, length 0
15:02:20.619715 ipsec0, OUT: IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: Flags [R.], seq 4173, ack 3663, win 0, length 0
^C
104 packets captured
104 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
console>
```

Main site UTM inbound packet capture when the problem occurs:

```
Router> packet-trace interface lan1 src-host 192.168.170.2 dst-host 192.168.169.4
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 68 bytes
13:35:03.378214 IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: S 2596326655:2596326655(0) win 8192 <mss 1402,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK>
13:35:03.409321 IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: . ack 2739636352 win 261
13:35:03.409488 IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: P 0:19(19) ack 1 win 261
13:35:06.454025 IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: . ack 20 win 261 <nop,nop,sack sack 1 {1:20} >
13:35:09.054995 IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: P 19:160(141) ack 20 win 261
13:35:09.123072 IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: P 160:294(134) ack 1229 win 256
13:35:09.156294 IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: P 294:491(197) ack 1288 win 256
13:35:09.189996 IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: . 491:1885(1394) ack 2525 win 261
13:35:09.190141 IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: P 1885:2224(339) ack 2525 win 261
13:35:09.220727 IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: P 2224:2661(437) ack 2786 win 260
13:35:09.264170 IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: P 2661:2858(197) ack 3159 win 258
13:35:09.264313 IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: P 2858:3327(469) ack 3159 win 258
13:35:09.293790 IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: P 3327:3380(53) ack 3308 win 258
13:35:09.293933 IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: P 3380:3417(37) ack 3308 win 258
13:35:09.322616 IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: P 3417:3470(53) ack 3345 win 258
13:35:09.358341 IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: P 3470:3523(53) ack 3398 win 257
13:35:09.387431 IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: P 3523:3576(53) ack 3451 win 257
13:35:09.415444 IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: P 3576:3629(53) ack 3504 win 257
13:35:09.447532 IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: P 3629:3682(53) ack 3557 win 257
13:35:09.474161 IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: P 3682:3735(53) ack 3610 win 257
13:35:09.586635 IP 192.168.170.2.58969 > 192.168.169.4.3389: P 3735:4172(437) ack 3663 win 256
13:35:09.596816 IP 192.168.170.2 > 192.168.169.4: icmp: 192.168.170.2 unreachable - need to frag (mtu 1434)
^C
22 packets captured
44 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
Router>
```

Main site UTM outbound packet capture when the problem occurs:

```
Router> packet-trace interface lan1 src-host 192.168.169.4 dst-host 192.168.170.2
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 68 bytes
13:35:03.379281 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: S 2739636351:2739636351(0) ack 2596326656 win 8192 <mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK>
13:35:03.419429 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: . ack 20 win 514
13:35:03.419439 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: P 1:20(19) ack 20 win 514
13:35:06.427459 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: P 1:20(19) ack 20 win 514
13:35:09.067035 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: P 20:1229(1209) ack 161 win 514
13:35:09.128270 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: P 1229:1288(59) ack 295 win 513
13:35:09.158237 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: P 1288:2525(1237) ack 492 win 512
13:35:09.192298 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: . ack 2225 win 506
13:35:09.192309 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: . ack 2225 win 512
13:35:09.192312 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: P 2525:2786(261) ack 2225 win 512
13:35:09.222233 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: P 2786:3159(373) ack 2662 win 510
13:35:09.266517 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: . ack 3328 win 507
13:35:09.266527 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: . ack 3328 win 514
13:35:09.266530 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: P 3159:3308(149) ack 3328 win 514
13:35:09.295276 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: . ack 3418 win 514
13:35:09.295286 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: P 3308:3345(37) ack 3418 win 514
13:35:09.331527 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: P 3345:3398(53) ack 3471 win 514
13:35:09.359430 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: P 3398:3451(53) ack 3524 win 514
13:35:09.388479 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: P 3451:3504(53) ack 3577 win 513
13:35:09.420695 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: P 3504:3557(53) ack 3630 win 513
13:35:09.448129 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: P 3557:3610(53) ack 3683 win 513
13:35:09.475201 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: P 3610:3663(53) ack 3736 win 513
13:35:09.592050 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: . 3663:5065(1402) ack 4173 win 511
13:35:09.592061 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: . 5065:6467(1402) ack 4173 win 511
13:35:09.592064 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: . 6467:7869(1402) ack 4173 win 511
13:35:09.897681 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: . 3663:5057(1394) ack 4173 win 517
13:35:10.506021 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: . 3663:5057(1394) ack 4173 win 517
13:35:11.706834 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: . 3663:4199(536) ack 4173 win 517
13:35:12.907933 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: . 3663:4199(536) ack 4173 win 517
13:35:14.105571 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: . 3663:5057(1394) ack 4173 win 517
13:35:16.510943 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: . 3663:5057(1394) ack 4173 win 517
13:35:21.335328 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: . 3663:5057(1394) ack 4173 win 517
13:35:30.935793 IP 192.168.169.4.3389 > 192.168.170.2.58969: R 5057:5057(0) ack 4173 win 0
^C
33 packets captured
66 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
Router>
```

`13:35:09.596816 IP 192.168.170.2 > 192.168.169.4: icmp: 192.168.170.2 unreachable - need to frag (mtu 1434)` seems to be the key.

Pings from the branch site to the RDSH server with Don't Fragment set fail at 1473 B:
[image]

RDP connections from and to the same hosts but via the general Internet / not via the IPsec VPN seem unaffected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reconfiguring the main site's ZyXEL ZyWALL USG 50 enabling the option `Ignore "Don't Fragment" setting in IP header` has resolved the issues.